# Hashed Password Logging In Error

Tags: php, sql

Okay, So I am hashing my password using 'sha1' when I define what the variable '$password' is, and then at the log in stage, I use 'sha1' again **but** my error message *Invalid login credentials* is the only thing to happen.

**Registration.php**

```
   $password = sha1($_POST['password']);
   $password_escaped = mysqli_real_escape_string ($db, $password);
   $query = "INSERT INTO admin (forename,surname,email,securityq, securitya,password) VALUES ('$forename_escaped','$surname_escaped','$email_escaped','$securityq_escaped','$securitya_escaped','$password_escaped')";
```

**Login.php**

```
    if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = sha1 ($_POST['pass']);
    include('connect-db.php');
    $query = mysqli_query ($db, "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email' AND  password = '$password'");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array ($query);
if(!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password']))
{
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['password'];
```

**Success or Failure Messages**

```
 echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Successful Login')
    window.location.href='adminhome.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
}
else
{
echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
    window.alert('Invalid Login Credentials')
    window.location.href='adminsignin.php';
    </SCRIPT>");
} 

}
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
SignIn();
}
```

What is wrong with this code that it wont let me log in with the hashed password?

Comment: You are open to **SQL-Injection** ! Please also stop using **mysql_*** functions are they are deprecated and will be removed from PHP 7, start using prepared statements and **mysqli_*** or **PDO** to avoid previous problems..

Comment: I am aware of the possible sql injection attacks on this piece of code I am about to add some parameters to prevent this. Have you nothing to share about my actual question though?

Comment: This is pretty much code. Maybe you should try to reduce the problem to the core and post only the relevant part including how you tried to get the hashes to work. Making a minimal example isn't the worst idea.

Comment: I've edited the entire post to narrow down the issue

Comment: Have you tried to print the query after inserting the variables. After this you should take a look into the `admin` table if the requested data does exist. You also don't have to escape the hashed password.

Comment: just tried printing it and recieve: Cachable fatal error Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string...... Okay yeah i dont know why I escaped that I was just doing it with many other variables didnt stop to think. I've checked the admin table and the hashed password is there

Comment: you cannot `echo $query` you have to echo the SQL string. Just do an additional step: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email' AND  password = '$password'"`.

Comment: I've posted an answer, without you @AbcAeffchen I wouldnt have come across this for a LONG time. Thankyou

Comment: You're welcome. This is just the normal way of debugging your code. Whenever something is not working you should try to get a look at what happens in each line exactly. Debuggers can make this process much faster and easier.

Comment: I'm new to php - I will remember this for next time

Comment: Also notice, that sha1 seems not to be save anymore. You should use PHPs [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function to get much more save password hashs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After printing my $query to see what password was getting compared to the database and inspecting the hashed password in the database, I realised that the one in the database had 10 characters missing, where I realised my VARCHAR was set to 30... and the password hash was 40!

After setting VARCHAR(40) the password hash worked straight away.

anyone with a similar issue to me (stupidity) make sure your values in the database are long enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few pitfalls with your code and a few possibilities to solve it.

The fast and dirty solve is to change the lines

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password =   ($_POST['pass']);
```

to

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password =   sha1($_POST['pass']); //you need to check the hashes not the password itself.
```

A much cleaner fix would be to use `password_hash` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)).

Your code would than be:

**To use mysqli db**

```
$myslqiDB = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
```

**To sign up**

```
$email = $myslqiDB->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$options = [
    'cost' => 12,
];
$password = $myslqiDB->real_escape_string(password_hash ($_POST['password'],PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options));

$query = "INSERT INTO admin (forename,surname,email,securityq, securitya,password) VALUES ('$forename','$surname','$email','$securityq','$securitya','$password')";

$data = $myslqiDB->query ($query)or die($myslqiDB->error());
```

**To login**

```
if (!empty($_POST['email']))
{
    $email = $myslqiDB->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['pass'];
    $query = $myslqiDB->query ("SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = '$email'");

    $row = $myslqiDB->fetch_assoc ($query);
    if(!empty($row['email']) AND !empty($row['password']))
    {
        if (password_verify ( $password , $row['password'] ) ){
            //loggedin
        }else{
            //wrong password.
        }
    }else{
        //no user with this email
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I've uploaded an ever so slightly outdated version here, I already have in my code 'sha1' before the $_POST['pass'] - but this still doesnt work, I'll try your other method

Comment: Check, I updated my other method and included all the code you need.